Temperature stable 800 Hz, 5 V square wave generator
I require a temperature stable 800 Hz with a small amount of adjustment 5 V square wave generator.
Is it best to go down the Crystal Oscillator and a CD4060 or use a 555 and cog caps.

What do you want to adjust? Frequency? Amplitude? Duty cycle? ...? How small or large an adjustment do you need to be able to make? How stable does it need to be after adjusting? How much temperature change do you need to allow for?

Have you considered other options? For example, Numerically-controlled-oscillators (NCO)? These are embedded in some microcontroller chips. A CD4060 xtal oscillator will have a very narrow adjustment range.

Adjust with a pot? Adjust with an input voltage? Adjust with MCU GPIO outputs?

Hi Phil! I'm afraid if you don't put numbers to "stable", and to "adjustable", then this is impossible to answer. If that's hard for you, help us help you: Simply describe your application, i.e., what you need this for, in the bigger picture, in your question! That's always a good idea.

In case your question gets closed before you finish writing that down in your question, we can always reopen questions that got closed, when through editing their problems were solved.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Which one to use totally depends on (a) how stable tolerance is enough for you and (b) over which temperature range you need it. Either both can achieve it, or only other, or neither. We don't know what components you intend to use. Or if you require a rubidium oscillator for your stability needs.

You can create a stable film cap and 1% fixed R stable oscillator with a fine-tuned f and variable amplitude. Use a comparator with a pull-up to regulated 5V=Vcc, a  "Schmitt trigger comparator circuit" with fixed % of positive feedback and centre-biased with a negative feedback shunt film Capacitor to ground to make a hysteretic oscillator. Alternatively, use a CMOS Schmitt Trigger and vary Vdd for amplitude and a large shunt Pot to tune f higher.
Until you define design specs, and say specify that you need better than 1% tolerances over X temp range and Y supply range, then you can use an XO with suitable counters, or better a uC with timer code or equiv.
FWIW commercial tolerances for cheap TCXO crystal oscillators can be 1 to few PPM error max or expensive ones for $250 are 1e-12 to 1e-10 and Rubidium Oscillators for low RF phase noise beyond your budget.

I am going to assume your application is not particularly precise.  Temperature stability is not much problem for a CMOS 555 timer with appropriately-stable timing components.  Something like a TLC555 timer and either COG or Film timing capacitor and a stable 1% timing resistor.  You can size the resistor a few percent low and place a temperature-stable trim pot in series with that resistor.
But you really need to precisely define your requirements.  As some of the comments suggest, please give us the larger picture.  What, exactly, are you trying to achieve?  Modify your question appropriately.
